# Automation of scripts to sync generation and capture of packets between different machines for different iterations

Tags: python, shell, networking, scripting, automation

I have the following scenario

Machine A: (Generator)

I am generating traffic using tcpreplay on Machine A.

So the generator script will call the following

```
tcpreplay --loop=100000 --intf1=eth0 64.pcap
# then I do the above for other pcaps, 128.pcap, 256.pcap etc
```

Machine B: (Monitoring and processing)

will capture the data and process them,

The following is are items to be included in the receive script.

```
#calls my capture daemon, should run even before the generator starts
./capture_start # takes some time to process

 # Here I need to stop the process (ctrl+c), then it will output file1.dat files

 # process the file1.dat
./capture_processing -i file1.dat -o file2.dat # generates file2.dat

 # analyze the file2.dat and generate the final result 
./capture_analysing file2.dat >> 64.log #similarly for other logs
```

I can automate the above for Machine A and B separately.

But how can I sync the Machine A and Machine B (ie, Machine B starts capture daemon, after than Machine A starts generating, once all packets arrive machine B stops and starts processing). This goes on for several loops of packet sizes.

How can I automate the above to run for several iterations and return logs.
Any suggestions/comments are welcome.

Comment: is Machine A and B a python script?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Machine A and B are servers and they run the scripts for generating and capturing traffic respectively. I have edited my question to be clear. Thanks

Comment: *nix Server or Windows?

Comment: *nix Server (running Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways to approach this.
I'd use Machine B to control Machine A via [sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) and code you implement to send and handle specific commands/messages to/from each machine.

You'd still need to start your script/daemon on both machines.

Your process would then be something like:

1. start script on machine A, it listens/waits for commands on a specific port
2. start script on machine B
3. calls `./capture_start` (send and capture traffic on a different port from your 'command' socket)
4. open a socket to machine A, send 'generate traffic' command
5. machine A receives request, generates traffic, sends 'i am finished' response to machine B
6. machine B receives 'i am finished' from machine A, and does capture processing and analysing